# Sending file in a Client-proxy-Server over TCP

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, network-programming, client-server

I am still a novice in network programming/python.
I want to write a python client-proxy-server program where client should be able to send a file content to proxy, proxy should be able to store it in a file and if need be I should be able to change the content of the file before forwarding it to the server and the response should be again stored at proxy side before sending it back to client.

All this over a TCP connection and for every new request from client a new TCP connection but for one complete cycle ( client->proxy->server->proxy->client) I need a persistent connection ( I dont know how to achieve this).

Is this even possible, like able to alter/save the file from client at proxy before forwarding to server.
Please point me to the right direction.
Any help will be hugely appreciated.
Thanks for your time and invaluable help/suggestions.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [examples at Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#example) provide a basic background for implementing a client-server system. Adding a proxy in between the two requires some application of the example code, though.

## A skeletal model for the client-proxy-server system

### Client

The client should do the following things:

1. Read the file that's going to get sent

   - `open()`, `fp.read()` etc.
2. Create a socket and establish a TCP connection to the proxy

   - `socket.socket()`, `proxysock.connect()` with `SOCK_STREAM`
3. Send the file data stored into a variable in step 1 to the proxy

   - `proxysock.sendall()`
4. Wait for an answer

   - `proxysock.recv()`
5. Close the connection

   - `proxysock.close()`

### Proxy

The proxy, being basically both a kind of a server and a client, should do the following things:

1. Create a listening socket, wait for incoming connections from the client, accept and store the handle of an incoming connection

   - `socket.socket()`, `proxyserversock.bind()`, `proxyserversock.listen()`, `proxyserversock.accept()`
2. Read the data from the incoming connection

   - `clientsock.recv()`
3. Store the received data into a file

   - `open()`, `fp.write()` etc.
4. Create a socket and establish a TCP connection to the server

   - `socket.socket()`, `serversock.connect()` again with `SOCK_STREAM`
5. Send the data received from the client onwards to the server

   - `serversock.sendall()`
6. Wait for an aswer

   - `serversock.recv()`
7. Pass the answer on to the client

   - `clientsock.sendall()`
8. Close the connections to the server and the client, but leave the listening socket on

   - `serversock.close()`, `clientsock.close()`

### Server

The server should do the following things:

1. Create a listening socket, wait for incoming connections from the proxy, accept and store the handle of an incoming connection

   - `socket.socket()`, `serversock.bind()`, `serversock.listen()`, `serversock.accept()`
2. Read the data from the incoming connection

   - `proxyclientsock.recv()`
3. Store the received data into a file

   - `open()`, `fp.write()` etc.
4. Send an answer to the proxy

   - `proxyclientsock.sendall()`
5. Close the connection, but leave the listening socket on

   - `proxyclientsock.close()`

## Additional notes

After implementing the basic model described above, you can easily start adding more features. For example, you could add a sleep in the proxy between steps 3 and 4 and instead of directly sending the data received from the client to the server, you could read the file and send the contents - this way you can manually change the file before it gets sent to the server.

I also suggest you read [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) if you want to really learn the basics of network programming. The examples are in C, but the basic principles also apply in Python (and other languages as well).

Comment: Thanks for wonderful explanation and this should definitely get me going.Just a quick one though, following your explanation, will the complete cycle be a persistent connection as by the looks of it, client<->proxy and proxy<->server connection seems to be mutually exclusive, so how to create/establish that relation across the board for one complete cycle or by default it will be taken care if i follow what you suggested?

Comment: @ramd With the proxy and the server running, each time a client starts the process of sending the file, the connections are established and they are closed only after the client has received the answer sent by the server through the proxy. So yes, the TCP connections at each communicating node (client, proxy and server) will be persistent throughout a complete cycle. Later on, if your project becomes more complicated, you might consider implementing some kind of [keepalive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) to ensure the connections stay connected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know your experience in socket programming. If you don't have understanding of sockets and how to handle it, it will be big learning curve [for me at least]. But I definately recommend you to checkout the twisted framework Python . http://twistedmatrix.com. I found it very well documented and has a big support. You can do so many things is very little time with little understanding.

Comment: thanks for the headsup, i have heard about this and also had a quick glance. So in twisted do we have something which gives us a ready made template/feature/framework to implement client-proxy-server model right out of box? Any pointers will help.Thanks

Comment: I haven't done Network programming in a while. I don't know if you will find exactly what you are looking for. But, you see Twisted is a big framework. Break down your program into small details. IF you know exactly what you are looking for, your code will be small and clean for the whole system. Now, Find ways to stop client connecting from server, since only proxy connects to the server. Maybe a secret password. And,If you define your protocal correctly, It should be very easy. Like a client handles 1 connection [Proxy], Proxy 2[client, server] , Server 1 [Proxy]. Hope that helps.